# How to divide a multiline string to a list of string, each containing a specific number of lines?

Tags: kotlin

I have a string like this:

```
1
00:01:22,416 --> 00:01:25,146
Hey, Jack, those racks
don't go up there.

2
00:01:25,153 --> 00:01:27,915
- What do you mean?
- They go in the parking lot.

3
00:01:27,921 --> 00:01:30,315
The ones with blue plastic go up there.

4
00:01:30,324 --> 00:01:34,161
Ah, okay, hey, sorry, I didn't realize.
```

I want to divide the string into a list of string, each containing a specific number of lines, for example, if the number is 5, each string should contain 5 lines, and if there is remaining, it would be inside another string. How to do that?

Comment: Are you sure you want a _fixed_ number of strings? In your example, some subtitles have two lines of text (making 5 lines total), and some have only one (making 4). (The [SubRip format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip) doesn't seem to have a limit on the number of text lines; 1–4 seem common.) For this format, it would seem much better to split on _blank_ lines.

Comment: @gidds Yes actually that's a better solution, my purpose is to divide large strings, so what I'm really doing is to split by 400 lines, so if it's possible, dividing for each 400 spaces would be appropriate.

Comment: @gidds I looked for a way to do that but I didn't find any way, is there a symbol that represents an empty line? Like \n is a line, but how could I know that the line is empty?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code in Kotlin.
As the tag is Kotlin I suppose you need Kotlin code.
You can also test it here: https://pl.kotl.in/GnuwwQSxd

```
fun divideStringIntoChunks(input: String, chunkSize: Int): List<String> {
    val lines = input.lines().map { it.trim() }
    val chunks = lines.chunked(chunkSize)
    return chunks.map { it.joinToString("\n") }
}

fun main() {
    val input = """
        1
        00:01:22,416 --> 00:01:25,146
        Hey, Jack, those racks
        don't go up there.

        2
        00:01:25,153 --> 00:01:27,915
        - What do you mean?
        - They go in the parking lot.

        3
        00:01:27,921 --> 00:01:30,315
        The ones with blue plastic go up there.

        4
        00:01:30,324 --> 00:01:34,161
        Ah, okay, hey, sorry, I didn't realize.
    """.trimIndent()

    val chunkSize = 5
    val dividedStrings = divideStringIntoChunks(input, chunkSize)
    dividedStrings.forEachIndexed { index, str ->
        println("String ${index + 1}:")
        println(str)
        println()
    }
}
```

Comment: @lukas.j it seems I did some copy paste error. The code in the link works. Did you check this link if it gives you the desired result. https://pl.kotl.in/GnuwwQSxd I am also fixing the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
val countOfSubtitles = 400

val result = input
  .split("\n\n")
  .chunked(countOfSubtitles)
  .map { it.joinToString("\n\n") }
```

Another option – depending on what happens with the chunks later in the application – would be to alternatively transform the input string into a List of data class instances. Might make working with the data easier. Something along this:

```
data class Subtitle (
  val number: Int,
  val timecodeStart: String,
  val timecodeEnd: String,
  val subtitles: List<String>
)

val subtitles = input
  .trimIndent()
  .split("\n\n")
  .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
  .map {
    val item = it.split("\n")
    Subtitle(
      number = item[0].toInt(),
      timecodeStart = item[1].substringBefore(" --> "),
      timecodeEnd = item[1].substringAfter(" --> "),
      subtitles = item.slice(2 until item.size)
    )
  }
  // .chunked(400)   // optional

subtitles.forEach(::println)
```

Output:

```
Subtitle(number=1, timecodeStart=00:01:22,416, timecodeEnd=00:01:25,146, subtitles=[Hey, Jack, those racks, don't go up there.])
Subtitle(number=2, timecodeStart=00:01:25,153, timecodeEnd=00:01:27,915, subtitles=[- What do you mean?, - They go in the parking lot.])
Subtitle(number=3, timecodeStart=00:01:27,921, timecodeEnd=00:01:30,315, subtitles=[The ones with blue plastic go up there.])
Subtitle(number=4, timecodeStart=00:01:30,324, timecodeEnd=00:01:34,161, subtitles=[Ah, okay, hey, sorry, I didn't realize.])
Subtitle(number=5, timecodeStart=00:12:34,567, timecodeEnd=00:12:56,789, subtitles=[Ah, okay, hey, sorry, I did suddenly realize.])
```