# Dividing a multiline string depending on empty lines

Tags: string, kotlin

See also this question: [How to divide a multiline string to a list of string, each containing a specific number of lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76322855/how-to-divide-a-multiline-string-to-a-list-of-string-each-containing-a-specific/76324977#76324977)

So I have SRT formatted string, I want to divide the string into chunks, currently I'm using this function:

```
fun divideStringIntoChunks(
    input: String,
    chunkSize: Int,
    fromLocal: String,
    intoLocale: String
): ArrayList<String> {
    val formattedInput = formatString(input)
    val lines = formattedInput.split("%0A")
    val chunks = lines.chunked(chunkSize)
    val result = ArrayList<String>()

    for (chunk in chunks) {
        val joinChunk = chunk.joinToString("%0A")

        val emptyLineAfterFormatted = joinChunk + "\n"
        result.add("https://translate.google.com/?sl=$fromLocal&tl=$intoLocale&text=$emptyLineAfterFormatted&op=translate")
    }

    return result
}
```

A sample of the SRT string:

```
1474
02:13:11,225 --> 02:13:13,425
Thank you. I love when
you call me Princess.

1475
02:13:14,762 --> 02:13:16,130
You work across the street?

1476
02:13:16,797 --> 02:13:17,799
Yeah.

1477
02:13:18,464 --> 02:13:20,098
Diamond exchange?
```

And also this function for formatting the string so it works with SRT:

EDIT:

Actually this function is for for encoding the SRT so that the format of the SRT would not change when passing it as a query.

```
fun formatString(input: String): String {
    val encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(input, "UTF-8")
    return encodedString.replace("+", "%20").replace("%2C", ",")
}
```

But when trying to divide a string for 400 lines(or any other number), some strings are cut off and are not showing, and also when making tha calculation for the SRT, which has 6664 lines, it divides it into 28 chunks, which is wrong if we divide 6664 with 400 lines.

So is there any way to divide it according to empty lines, instead of lines, since each dialogue in the SRT is divided by a line, so if I want to divide by 400, where would be 400 dialogue inside each chunk.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I think you just need to alter you split to be `split("\n\n")`
What is SRT?

Comment: A file extension for movies subtitle, the format of the SRT is the same as the string displayed above.

Comment: An SRT format description is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip. You seem to be conflating two separate concepts, which complicates your code (and your question). The SRT format does not use URL encoding. You only need to URL-encode when you send a string to Google Translate. Keep the two separate: process your SRT file first without URL encoding, then encode it and send it to Google.

Comment: Sorry, the question has been edited, I tried both ways, encoding the string so it can be used in the URL, and then divide it, as shown in the question, and dividing the string, then encoding it before making the request (I tried this before) and both cause almost the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as follows:

1. First, it splits the whole SRT document into a list of individual subtitles
2. Then it gathers the individual subtitles into chunks, each chunk being a string of subtitles separated by blank lines
3. Finally, it URL-encodes each subtitle chunk and adds it to a Google Translate URL

If you click on the URLs that are printed out, you can see that they get translated correctly.

```
import java.net.URLEncoder

fun divideStringIntoChunks(input: String, chunkSize: Int, fromLocal: String, intoLocale: String) =
    input
        .split("\n\n")
        .chunked(chunkSize) { listOfSubtitles -> listOfSubtitles.joinToString("\n\n") }
        .map { subtitlesSeparatedByBlankLines ->
            "https://translate.google.com/?sl=$fromLocal&tl=$intoLocale" +
            "&text=${URLEncoder.encode(subtitlesSeparatedByBlankLines, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20").replace("%2C", ",")}" +
            "&op=translate"
        }

fun main() {
    val sampleSRT = """
        1474
        02:13:11,225 --> 02:13:13,425
        Thank you. I love when
        you call me Princess.
        
        1475
        02:13:14,762 --> 02:13:16,130
        You work across the street?
        
        1476
        02:13:16,797 --> 02:13:17,799
        Yeah.

        1477
        02:13:18,464 --> 02:13:20,098
        Diamond exchange?
        """.trimIndent()

    divideStringIntoChunks(sampleSRT, 2, "en", "fr")
        .forEach(::println)
}
```

Comment: The SRT string contains a lot of content, that's why I want to divide it into chunks that contain a certain size of dialogues, sending it one by one would need a lot of time to complete.

Comment: @Roony I've edited my code so that it chunks the subtitles.